# TypeError: format: a number is required, not str

Tags: python

```
import pymysql
try:
    stmt = "INSERT INTO employees (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, AGE) VALUES (%s, %s, %d)"
    data = [('Jagdish', 'Mathpal',34)]
    conn = pymysql.connect("xxx.xx.xx.xx","test","test","testdb")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(stmt, data)
    conn.commit()
    print("Record Inserted Successfully")
```

Why there is an Type Error while trying to insert an Digit in table "employees".

```
MariaDB [testdb]> desc employees;
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| FIRST_NAME | char(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| LAST_NAME  | char(20) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| AGE        | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| SEX        | char(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| INCOME     | float    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jmathpal/PycharmProjects/Learning_Automation/test1.py", line 7, in <module>
    cursor.executemany(stmt, data)
  File "C:\Users\jmathpal\PycharmProjects\Learning_Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 199, in executemany
    self.rowcount = sum(self.execute(query, arg) for arg in args)
  File "C:\Users\jmathpal\PycharmProjects\Learning_Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 199, in <genexpr>
    self.rowcount = sum(self.execute(query, arg) for arg in args)
  File "C:\Users\jmathpal\PycharmProjects\Learning_Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 168, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\jmathpal\PycharmProjects\Learning_Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 147, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

Comment: Try replacing the `%d` with `%s`?

Comment: try take off list from data? Just like this `data = ('Jagdish', 'Mathpal',34)`

Comment: @HjSin I don’t think that will work, since he is using `executemany()`.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Ahh I see..

Comment: Yes It's adding the Record now, But what was the problem when I was using %d or %f for float value ?

Comment: @Jagdish see the answer by vikash kumar.

Answer (score 2):

PyMySQL convert all the objects including integer to formatter quoted string.
SO it is advisable to use only %s as placeholder.

For more details, please refer to the following documentation:

https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute